# $K \in \mathbb{R}^d$ compact, with fixed open cover is there $\epsilon > 0: \forall x \in K \exists$ a set in the cover that contains $B_\epsilon (x)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Let $K \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be compact and $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ an open cover of $K$. I want to show, that $\exists \epsilon > 0 : \forall x \in K \exists i \in I$ with $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U_i$.

Comment: This is a well-known theorem, called "Lebesgue's number lemma": for a proof check the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma

Comment: @Crostul Thank you very much!